# An App has disappeared from my phone, but the store says I have it, so I can't get it back

Tags: apps, store

The app is "Dominion Picker", but I don't think the app is at fault.  My wife has the same phone (Nokia 920) and OS (Windows 8.1), and hers is fine.  I have had the app for quite a while, and got an update for it recently.  However, it is not anywhere on my lists, and so I can't find it to delete or update.

Comment: Have you tried anything to attempt to resolve the issue, such as restarting your phone? If you have please list the steps to better help those who might be able to answer your question.

Comment: If the app is already installed, you'll see a "view" button in the store, right? What happens if you press that?

Comment: I have rebooted the phone a few times.  View takes me to my front page (because it can't find it, either.)

Answer (score 2):

Please try these steps:

1. Go to [*Windows Phone Store*](http://www.windowsphone.com/store).
2. Sign in with your Microsoft account that is linked to your Windows Phone
3. Hover over your phone panel and go to **Purchase History**.
4. Here you have got all the apps you have installed so far on this account. Find the app you are looking for and use **Reinstall** option to have it once again in your device.

Hope it helps finding that app on your apps list.

Comment: The app shows on the list, but when I click Reinstall, "Reinstall" changes to "App wasn't purchased" (even though there it is, on the list).

Comment: Its a bit strange! Try purchasing that app (Dominion Picker) again.

Comment: Since the app appears as "Installed" in the App Store, I do not see a re-purchase option.

Answer (score 1):

- Download it from the web store in your Desktop (find for download link, is difficult to see).
- Put somewhere in your phone via **USB**.
- Go to the Store app in your phone.
- Hit the "**...**" button. You should see "*Install local app*" or something like this there.

Maybe it can help in this case.